# How to visualize MySQL data with python web development modules

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas, linux

I have a requirement to visualize Linux servers patching status. So I added the patching status into MYSQL but still I want to visualize those data on web using python.

I want to visualize the data on the web page from MySQL table using python web development

I am trying to provide visibility to everyone in the project can find the details simply accessing the website.

Comment: THis is a bit of a broad question, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could try [anvil](https://anvil.works/) as a pure python we application.

Comment: Question only specifies what you want to do, not what help you require.

Answer (score 0):

Broad answer to a broad question:

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html): read the sql into a dataframe grid

[Dash datatable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable):  to visualise the dataframe and generate a web page

You'll need to replace the args in pd.read_sql below with information from your own use case.

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql( "[your sql connection and query]" )

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And you need a way of deploying the result. I like using a combination of nginx + docker. [Here is an example](https://github.com/yaojiach/docker-dash) of adding a dash application to a docker image.